# separate background image for one page angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an angularjs project, where I have a splash screen (home.html), a gallery page and an about page.

I am trying to set an image to display on the splash page only.  I have set up a pageClass in the controllers, but cant seem to set a separate css style to it by typing:

```
.home.body {
...
}
```

but that doesn't work. I have tried absolutely every solution I could find on here and other tutorial pages, but I can't seem to get it working. I also am new to angularjs so I more than likely have done something wrong!

Can anyone help me on adding a background image to just one page? Not sure what code you want to see.

Comment: add inline css like `<div background="url("imageUrl.jpg")">...`

Comment: no that does not work, I have tried that. :-)

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle or something equivalent so that we can help debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<body class="home">
....
</body>
```

css

```
body.home {
...
}
```

Comment: What is your html? try .home body {...}

Comment: yep tried that too. I ended up putting a style tag in the head section. its a hack but it works :-)